# How to find a key of a hashmap which has only one value

Tags: java, hashmap

Can anyone help me to find key which has only one value below is the `hashmap` :

It's a `Map<String,List<String>>`

```
key    values

A      [cricket, writing]
B      [READING, coding]
c      [music]
```

The output should be:

`c` because there is only one value in the `List`

Comment: Give the de definition of the map please, is it `Map<String,List<String>>` ?

Comment: yes its Map<String,List<String>>

Comment: Any Java `Map` is a mapping between a unique key and a value. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @ EJP how to print a key which has only one value.. is my question?

Comment: Code is main way of communiation

Comment: @EJP I think one value means : List size of 1 / But Sainath be careful, each key as ONE value, which is ONE list but this list can have multiple value after

Comment: code should print "c" as it has only one value i.e, music

Comment: All `Map` keys have only one value. Your values appear to consist of comma-separated values, which is probably already a mistake, but you can't expect the `Map` API to understand that. I suggest you need a `Map<String, List<String>>`.

Comment: @EJP you're a bit late ^^ look comments 15min ago, he said he use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the pairs of the map String / List, and find the one where the size of the lst is 1 :

*Classic forLoop solution* :

```
String keyOneValue="";
for(Map.Entry<String,List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()){
    if(entry.getValue().size()==1){
        keyOneValue = entry.getKey();
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(keyOneValue);  // c
```

So when the condition will be `true` you'll save the key in a variable, and `break;` is to stop the loop beause you've find one

---

*Java 8 Stream solution for find ONE element* :

```
String keyOneValue = map.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().size()==1)
                        .findFirst()
                        .get()
                        .getKey();
```

---

*Java 8 Stream solution for find ALL key with one value* :

```
List<String> keyOneVal = map.entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().size()==1)
                            .map(entry -> entry.getKey())
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: correct the map can have multiple result in this case you can remove the `break`

Comment: Many thanks @azro it worked.Thanks lot for the help..

Comment: @azro can you suggest some online link or tutorials or text books to learn collection concept like map,it will be a great help. thanks

Comment: @SainathPawar You ask the keys, and not the entries, don't understand why you changed the accepted answer, not cool

Comment: @azro I am new to stack overflow I thought I can accept two answers

Comment: Help needed@azro can you suggest some online link or tutorials or text books to learn collection concept like map,it will be a great help. thanks

Comment: @SainathPawar okok sorry, that's true, you cannot do that ;)

Comment: @SainathPawar I do not have particular tuto ^^ Look around here [Doc Stack Java](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/topics) or just look on Google 'Map example' ;) there is thousand of it

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way to do this (Java 8)

```
List<String> onlyOneValue = map.keySet().stream()
    .filter(x-> map.get(x)!=null && map.get(x).size()==1)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(onlyOneValue);//C
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner solution using streams

```
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("A", Arrays.asList("cricket", "writing"));
map.put("B", Arrays.asList("READING", "coding"));
map.put("C", Arrays.asList("music"));

List<Entry<String, List<String>>>  singleValueEntries =  map.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue().size() == 1).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: can you suggest some online link or tutorials or text books to learn collection concept like a map, it will be a great help. thanks